# Android Trim mp4 file(remote,smb)

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, mp4

Task: trim mp4-video(remote) from *n* sec to *m* sec. For access use [samba](https://jcifs.samba.org/)

1) I try to find library using ffmpeg. [Example](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java). But this library doesn't support smb protocol.

2)I try to use [mp4parser](https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser). But I can't combine *jcifs + mp4parser*

3)I tried to write the library myself. It's poor trick. Not like.

How best to solve this problem. Need help(advice)

Comment: First download the video using your Samba library. then use ffmpeg to do the trimming. use samba again to upload the new trimmed file

Comment: Thank you. But if not download file (size from 1Gb and more)? ТNeed to download part of the file

Comment: the file should be on local storage if you want to perform trimming on your end. else it should be done on Server where the samba is installed

Comment: if jcifs.smb.SmbFile can open the InputStream, why can't I download correct fragment of the file?